# PHP log-log graph generation

Tags: php, graphics

I sampled a small wikipedia collection from 2008 and trying generate a graph similar to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia-n-zipf.png 
from the processing I did. I have word frequencies and ranks of words. How can I generate the graph on the fly from the data I collected? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to generate PNG charts on the fly?

This [Page](http://www.codediesel.com/php/6-excellent-charting-libraries-for-php/) lists a few great chart engines for PHP. If you want to generate graphics using PHP for word frequencies, my personal favorite is [PCHART](http://www.pchart.net/) It is a really nice library to generate charts like that.

[Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) is completely free  and doesn't use as much server power, but you have much less control over caching, styling, etc. The key difference here is that the actual image generation is done by Google.

If you want it to look exactly like that, you can use any of them and use the most basic settings to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the google chart api / graph tools.

You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Line charts documentation and [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html)